# Add column to SELECT IF Row Count > 1

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

Any suggestions or ideas are welcomed and maybe it can't be done... here is my main SELECT :

```
SELECT * From(
SELECT MODATA.CITEM, MODATA.QTREQ, MODATA.UNMSR, MODATA.CDESC, MODATA.USRSQ AS SQ, MODATA.OPRWU, SLQNTY.LLOCN, SLQNTY.LQNTY, ROW_NUMBER()     OVER (PARTITION BY CITEM ORDER By CITEM) as L, MODATA.FLSTK, 
MODATA.ISQTY, (QTREQ - ISQTY) as finalQty, SLQNTY.HOUSE, MOMAST.FITWH
FROM MODATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN SLQNTY ON SLQNTY.ITNBR = MODATA.CITEM
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOMAST ON MOMAST.ORDNO = MODATA.ORDNO
WHERE MODATA.ORDNO = 'M889360'  AND FLSTK != 'U' AND FLSTK != 'C' AND (SLQNTY.HOUSE=MOMAST.FITWH OR HOUSE IS NULL)) AS X
```

Which pulls up all items and if an item has more than 1 it does the row count which then I do this to only bring me the 1st item in the list

```
WHERE X.L = 1
ORDER BY X.SQ
```

My data before I do  the WHERE X.L = 1 looks like this:
[image]

My issue is... i want to have another column on the right that shows an X or a 1 IF the item has more than one row... then I can do a sort by that to put the multiple location items at the top.  Any ideas I'm drawing blanks as to if it can be done.  Ideally want to sort by X then I'll do my X.L = 1 to only pull the item once but still have a trigger to show that there is more than one location on that item.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

```
SELECT * From(
SELECT MODATA.CITEM, MODATA.QTREQ, MODATA.UNMSR, MODATA.CDESC, MODATA.USRSQ AS SQ, MODATA.OPRWU, SLQNTY.LLOCN, SLQNTY.LQNTY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CITEM ORDER By CITEM) as L, MODATA.FLSTK, 
MODATA.ISQTY, (QTREQ - ISQTY) as finalQty, SLQNTY.HOUSE, MOMAST.FITWH, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SLQNTY WHERE SLQNTY.ITNBR = MODATA.CITEM AND SLQNTY.LQNTY != 0  AND (SLQNTY.HOUSE=MOMAST.FITWH OR HOUSE IS NULL)) AS T
FROM MODATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN SLQNTY ON SLQNTY.ITNBR = MODATA.CITEM
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOMAST ON MOMAST.ORDNO = MODATA.ORDNO
WHERE MODATA.ORDNO = 'M838860'  AND FLSTK != 'U' AND FLSTK != 'C' AND (SLQNTY.HOUSE=MOMAST.FITWH OR HOUSE IS NULL)) AS X
WHERE X.L = 1
ORDER BY X.T DESC
```